# C# UI Thread Unresponsive

Tags: c#, multithreading, ui-thread

I have a function that adds a lot of files to a collection and does a lot of actions on each of them.

This causes the program (main thread) to become unresponsive.

How can I determine the cause and address the problem?

Comment: Start your task in a different thread. Which UI do you use? WinForms or WPF?

Comment: use a backgroundworker to do stuff that takes time on a seperate thread so that UI thread does not hang.

Answer (score 1):

Use the BackgroundWorker object. You can inform the user with the progress of the operation by using the ReportProgress and ProgressChanged event.

```
private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    backgroundWorker1.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
    backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
}

private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{

    // .. stuff that takes long

    backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(10);

    // .. stuff that takes long

    backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(20);

    // .. stuff that takes long

    backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(100);
}

private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    // Done !
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use another thread.

```
Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart( () => {
   IntensiveCalculationCode();
}));

t.Start();
```

You can also invoke the UI thread from inside the thread by invoking the dispatcher. They are not exactly the same on Windows Forms and WPF though.

Comment: i am using WPF what is the different?

Comment: on windows forms i don't remember exactly, but in WPF you invoke the dispatcher, something like `Dispatcher.Invoke(()=>{ CodeThatModifiesUIElementsSuchAsChangingTextboxText(); } );`